# Pointer in the main modified in a function without pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Let me give an example to understand my question :

```
void fct1()
{
 int T[20];
 int* p=T;//the goal is to modify this pointer (p)
 fct2(&p);
}
void fct2(int** p)
{
  (*p)++;//this will increment the value of the original p in the fct1
}
```

What i want is to avoid pointers and do it only with references , it's possible ?

Comment: Have you *tried* using a reference? What went wrong? (Also, please don't tag questions about references with [c]. There are no references in C.)

Comment: I'm working with visual c++ , and i'd like to use references but i don't know how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using references.

```
void fct2(int* &p) {
    p++;
}
```

Comment: this will also increment original pointer

Comment: even then this is pointer and reference not only reference

Comment: "do it only with references", it is not what you wanted OP

Comment: i mean avoiding the second pointer , sorry for being unprecise, i'm still new here ^^"

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the iterators provided by `std::array` if possible:

```c++
void fct1()
{
    std::array<int, 20> l;
    auto it = l.begin();
    fct2(it);
}

template<class I>
void fct2(I& it)
{
    ++it;
}
```